# How to set cascade deleting properly in Entity Framework 6 when I have two foreign keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-delete, cascade

I have below example and I need to have behaviour: when I delete `RoundAssetT`, I don't want to delete his `assetOccurrences`... I can't figure out how to set this relation in modelBuilder.

```
public class RoundAssetT 
{
    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("RoundT")]
    public int RoundTId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2), Key, ForeignKey("AssetT")]
    public int AssetTId { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetT AssetT { get; set; }
    public virtual RoundT RoundT { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetOccurrenceT> AssetOccurrencesT { get; set; }
}

public class AssetOccurrenceT
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("RoundAssetT")]
    public int? RoundTId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("RoundAssetT")]
    public int? AssetTId { get; set; }

    public virtual RoundAssetT RoundAssetT { get; set; }

    public string NameAOt { get; set; }
}
```

Could someone tell me how to set up this relation in Entity Framework 6?

Answer (score 0):

`AssetOccurrenceT.RoundAssetT` would have to be optional since you want to be able to delete `RoundAssetT`s without also deleting referencing `AssetOccurrenceT`s

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetOccurrenceT>()
    .HasOptional(ao => ao.RoundAssetT)
    .WithMany(ra => ra.AssetOccurrencesT);
```

Comment: okey, but I just need to add cascade delete ( false ) to above code?

Comment: I don’t think it’s necessary

Comment: You have right, I will give You best answer , thanks a lot ! could You just also explain me, is there any possiblity to remove not remove value of assetId?

Comment: Are you asking if you can keep the FK value after you delete the entity it references?  Look into soft deletes